# Different legal operations on the same inequality yield contradicting results

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Consider the inequality $$\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}<\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)^2}$$ Get rid of $\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$ and bring $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{2n+2}$ together I obtain $$\frac{4n+3}{(2n+1)2(n+1)}-\frac{1}{2n^2}<-\frac{1}{2(n+1)^2}$$ Multiply by $2(n+1)^2$ I obtain $$\frac{(4n+3)(n+1)}{2n+1}-\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2<-1$$ Which I reducte to $$\frac{(4n+3)(n+1)}{2n+1}<\frac{2n+1}{n^2}\Rightarrow 4n^2+4n+1<4n^4+7n^3+3n^2$$ I obtained the last inequality by cross multiplying. Note that $n\in N$. However if I start again from the same inequality but move the $\frac{1}{2n^2}$ to the RHS I obtain $$\frac{4n+3}{(2n+1)2(n+1)}<\frac{1}{2n^2}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)^2}\Rightarrow \frac{4n+3}{(2n+1)2(n+1)}<\frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{2n^2(n+1)^2}$$ Now I multiply by $2(n+1)$ to obtain $$\frac{4n+3}{2n+1}<\frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)}\Rightarrow n^2(n+1)(4n+3)<(2n+1)^2$$ We see that the LHS will have a degree of $4$ but the LHS will have a degree of $2$, and I just can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: $\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2=1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}$ ?

Comment: Ah, I missed the $-1$. I apologise.

Comment: The problem seems to be the line after "Which I reduce to": the $<$-sign on the right of the implication should be a $>$-sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line above "I obtained...", you reversed the inequality.  If you switch it, your two results are the same.

Comment: @Gianluca  It exactly answers the question.  I didn't critique or ask for clarification.  He asked where his mistake was.  I told him.

Comment: I'm sorry, I read something wrong! I am so sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Cross-multiplying across an inequality is extremely dangerous. For example, say I ask you to solve $\frac{1}{x - 1} < \frac{1}{x}$. You cross-multiply, obtaining $x < x - 1$, which is clearly false, and conclude there is no such number. But $x = 0.5$ is clearly a solution of the original inequality: $\frac{1}{-0.5} < \frac{1}{0.5}$. The problem is that **when you multiply both sides of an inequality by a negative number, the inequality reverses**. The thing is, when the thing you're multiplying by is a variable, you don't know whether it's negative! In the example I gave, the "correct" $x - 1$ is negative, so multiplying by that should have reversed the inequality.

To solve an inequality like this, you need to use a little bit of a different approach. Everything up through $\frac{(4n + 3)(n+1)}{2n+1} < \frac{2n+1}{n^2}$ is fine; multiplying by $2(n+1)^2$ wasn't a problem because that's positive for all $n$. But for the next part, you need to multiply by $2n+1$, which might require flipping the inequality. So do it separately for each case. IF $2n+1$ is positive, you're correct; if not, the inequality is reversed.

Comment: But $2n+1$ is positive since $n\in N$ as noted.